# Accessing flutter Form key from AppBar actions in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to access Form key to validate if form data in valid from AppBar action in flutter app , and then manipulate the data.

**This is my code**

Flutter build method:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  _buildDoctor(),
                  const SizedBox(width: 10),
                  _buildDate(),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              _buildRemark(),
              const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              _buildFormSet(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

And this is my State class

```
class _SalesPage extends State<SalesPage> {
final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
...
}
```

And this is my AppBar

```
AppBar(
        title: const Text('Add Sales'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.save),
            onPressed: () {
              final form = Form.of(context);
              if (form!.validate()) {
                
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: What errors you get after running the snippet?

Comment: null value from the `form!.validate()`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `_formKey.currentState!.validate();` works for me.

```dart
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              final validated = _formKey.currentState!.validate();
              print(validated);
            },
            child: Text("validated"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TextFormField(
                  validator: (value) {
                    return value!.isEmpty ? "Type" : null;
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```